# Where to pass runtime argument in wrapper.conf file in java service wrapper?

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper

Iam trying to create window service for my jar application. Application needs an argument and System property value while runtime. I dont know where to give argument value and system variable value in wrapper.conf file. please help me. I am getting the below error

wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | WrapperManager: Initializing...
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
jvm 1    |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class} [app_arguments]
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | Where:
jvm 1    |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
jvm 1    |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
jvm 1    |                   application.
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.

Answer (score 2):

If one is looking for a command-line-argument-like argument, how about [wrapper.app.parameter.N](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-app-parameter-n.html) (parameters for the application) and [wrapper.java.additional.N](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-java-additional-n.html) (parameters for JVM)

For example:

```
wrapper.app.parameter.1=myargument
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

The looking at this [example configuration file](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/props-example-config.html), it appears that you need to set the `wrapper.java.mainclass` property.

Comment: +1.  This is the same place I would have pointed him if you didn't do it first.  Raja needs to fill in that configuration file with proper values.